# Is there a way to calculate the photoelectric effect in QED via a Feynman diagram?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, photoelectric-effect

The photoelectric effect is the historic origin of the quantum particle description of light. From it we learn that when light is shone onto a metal single photons interact with single electrons in the metal which are ejected if the absorbed energy is larger than the binding energy of the metal.

The (free) process is:

$$e^-+\gamma\rightarrow e^-.$$

However, this process violates conservation of energy (all final states are real particles). Of course the reason the process occurs is because the electron is initially bound (not free), and some energy goes into releasing the electron from the metal potential.

The question is, is there anyway to do this calculation in QED, somehow incorporating the binding energy in the calculation?

Comment: Why would the process violate energy conservation? You just said yourself where the energy goes. Can QED analyze an electron that is bound weakly to a very large crystal lattice? Why not? http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1809. In http://www.scribd.com/doc/148001167/The-photoelectric-effect-without-photons Lamb and Scully argue that one does not have to quantize the radiation field, at all, to explain the photoelectric effect, and they give a reference to a paper of theirs in which they do. This sounds a bit like a case of insufficient effort. Did you even google this?

Comment: Consider the simpler case of the photo-ionization of a hydrogen atom - what is known in astrophysics as a "bound-free transition".  It looks just like bremsstrahlung in reverse, except that the electron is bound to start with.  How this is handled in QED I couldn't say, but it certainly can be.

Comment: @CuriousOne, before asking I did find 0910.1809. As the authors state, "the photo electric effect in the early experiments is produced by weak, non-coherent radiation of high frequency... whereas [the subject of the present paper] the radiation is weak, of high frequency, and coherent." Firstly, I'm interested in the photon description (not coherent radiation). Secondly, they use non-relativisitc QED, not fully covariant QED. And lastly, what they do looks highly rigorous and mathematical, whereas you can see from the title I'm looking for a Feynman diagram type explanation.

Comment: @CuriousOne, the second paper you mention is off topic. I'm not asking how to solve the problem, I'm asking how to solve the problem in QED.

Comment: @akrasia, this is exactly the kind of thing that I was thinking. And I agree the model would need to be something simple like an atom. Actually, I was thinking of something like Mott scattering where the $otimes$ is inserted to handle elastic scattering. But in the photoelectric effect, is is inelastic, so not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @CuriousOne, BTW- I didn't say that the photoelectric effect violates conservation of energy or anything stupid like that. The free process written above doesn't occur because it violates conservation of energy. Its a simple SR kinematic calculation, just set total ingoing four momentum to total outgoing 4 momentum, square, and work in ingoing electrons frame and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that photoelectricity is a messy process involving multiple interactions.

The photon transfers energy to the metal by exciting an electron within it, however the excited electron rattles around in the metal lattice transferring energy to anything it collides with. The quantum efficiency of photoelectron ejection from a metal surface is in the order of $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-6}$, so in all but 0.001% to 0.0001% of cases the electron energy is transferred to lattice vibrations (heat!) and no photoelectron is produced. In a very small number of cases enough energy is transferred to another electron to eject it from the metal.

I don't know enough about QED to speak definitively, but I'd be very surprised if anything this complicated could be usefully described using QED.

Comment: Well, how about we change from "metal" to "semiconductor" and just use QED to calculate the initial energy of the electron at ejection?

Comment: @Carl, I don't mind if metal or semiconductor. If the calculation is easier with a semiconductor because of the problems with the metal mentioned by John, then please provide that calculation as an answer. I'm still not sure how to "use QED" in this case.

Comment: The photoelectric effect can be made to have a quantum efficiency of nearly one these days. Your digital camera wouldn't work otherwise, neither would solar panels. And please check the quantum efficiency of real world photomultiplier tubes.

Comment: @CuriousOne: the question asks *light is shone onto a metal* and the quantum efficiency for photoelectron ejection from a metal is in the range I gave. Neither CCDs nor solar panels eject electrons, they work by exciting electrons between bands. This happens in a metal too, but that's just the first step in a process leading to ejection of an electron from the metal surface.

Comment: @JohnRennie: If you insist, PMTs do emit electrons and they have quantum efficiencies near one, just as well. It does not seem important to me to make a distinction between the photoelectric effect and the inner photoelectric effect within the question of the OP.

Comment: @CuriousOne: A photomultiplier tube uses a thin metal film and the electron is ejected in the same direction as the incident photon - the quantum efficiency for this process is indeed very high. In photoelectron emission from a metal surface the photon also generates a fast moving electron with a high quantum efficiency, but that electron is moving in the same direction as the photon, just as in a PMT, so it's moving down into the bulk of the metal.

Comment: For photoemission to occur the primary electron has to transfer energy to the lattice, and the lattice then transfer enough energy back to a different electron near the surface to eject it. It's this seconday process that has the extremely low quantum efficiency, which is hardly surprising given its haphazard nature. It's also the complexity of this secondary process that would make it hard to handle using QED. The overall quantum efficiency is in the range I cited.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thank you for admitting that you are wrong about the efficiency of the photoelectric effect. I did, by the way, use PMTs for a significant stretch of my career, so I think I have a good idea about how they work. None of the handwaving makes your mistake go away. What you are describing is a capture mechanism that happens AFTER the photoelectric effect, which has absolutely nothing to do with the photoelectric effect.

Comment: @CuriousOne: what I am talking about is the number of electrons ejected from a metal surface per incident photon, and that is in the range $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-6}$. You're talking about the number of electrons per photon ejected from a thin metal film.

Comment: @JohnRennie: And here I thought we were talking about the photoelectric effect, but OK, if you need it... I'll give it to you, because "this" is getting highly boring and has nothing to do with physics.