# An S-matrix description of the photoelectric effect?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, s-matrix-theory

As is well known, the photoelectric effect is an experimental phenomenon that had enormous historical importance for the emergence of the concept of photons and quantum mechanics itself. As is well known, when a light source radiates the surface of the metal (we could think of photons described by a wave function or incident collision state) it happens that there is a threshold frequency $\nu_0$ such that: (a) if the photons that make up this radiation have a frequency $\nu < \nu_0$ there is no emission of electrons (b) if the photons have a frequency $\nu \ge \nu_0$ then we observe an outgoing flow of photons proportional to the intensity of the radiation and where the minimum momentum of the photons is proportional to $h(\nu-\nu_0)/c$.

However, despite the simplicity of the phenomenon, I have not seen a precise of approximate mathematical description of such scattering according to the standard S-matrix formalism. This is because I also haven't seen a detailed description of the physics of the problem (is there a Hamiltonian interaction here?). We could define an incident photonic state and define a state of electrons and emergent photons, and see from the S-matrix's own definition that the probability of electron emission is 0 below $\nu_0$ and positive for the presence of components in the radiation with $\nu > \nu_0$ (I mean that a Fourier representation of the incident state has non-zero components for frequency $\nu > \nu_0$).
In short, someone could show a bit of how the mathematics of the standard quantum scattering formalism and in particular the S-matrix formalism apply to the photoelectric effect.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132885/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-photoelectric-effect-in-qed-via-a-feynman-diagra

Comment: @Albert I have deleted the link you give because there have been such changes over the years that the links given in the post have deteriorated and are nonsense

Comment: Berestetskii, Lifshitz, Pitaevskii, 'Quantum Electrodynamics' discusses the Photoelectric Effect in QED.

Comment: look at the plot that gives the photoelectric effect http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html .note that it is the maximum kinetic energy on the y axis that shows the effect.

Comment: this link downloads the book referred by @bolbteppa https://charmille.art/books/Landau_Lifshitz_T4.pdf